# I have to print using print command where my printer is network printer with IP?

Tags: windows, command

I am trying

```
print /d:<ipaddressofnetworkprinter> test.txt
```

error I am geting is:

```
Unable to initialize device <ipofprinter>
```

I know we can do this with network printer by its queue name
(\ServerName\ShareName) but here I have only IP printer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
lpr -S (printer ip address) -P (Give it a name) (file location)
sample
lpr -S 192.168.1.197 -P SLC Branch C:\test.txt